# Does freedom of movement enable you to tumble underwater?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

Tumbling is impossible in a deep bog, and presumably also in any kind of aquatic terrain. But what about the *freedom of movement* spell (and related magic items, eg. Pearl of the Sirines), which allows the subject to move and attack normally while underwater?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The spell description of [freedom of movement](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/freedomOfMovement.htm) says that you can move and attack 'normally' while underwater and you can normally tumble, so I would say yes.